# OpenCart 1.5 Captcha не работает

Tags: php, opencart, captcha

Подскажите пожалуйста, не работает каптча, даже если вводишь правильные символы, все равно пишет что код с картинки введен не верно, может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой

Comment: Она модульная? Попробуйте переподключить её. Или даже перезалить на сервер.

Comment: Капча родная или модуль какой-то?

Comment: Ошибки в журнале есть? Не работает везде или только в отзывах или контактах?

Comment: Не работала только в отзывах, Она родная

Comment: дайте ссылку на страничку где она неработает чтобы проверить !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у меня подозрения что несколько капчей!

было такое уже что именно на отзывах повторно отправляется кача, и необходимо просто проверить, вызвать переменную которая генерит капчей и сделать вывод её  в какую-то малозаметную переменную и по ним просмотреть код, если она несколько раз встречается, то скорее всего неправильная компановка кода !